# Why is my bootstrap overflow scrollbar not showing up?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to get a scrollbar next to my table but its not showing up.
This is my code:

```
 <style>
    .list
    {
        max-height:100px;        
    }
  </style>

 <div class = "overflow-auto list">
                    <tr>
                        <td> 1 </td>
                        <td>26.10.2020</td>
                        <td>63</td>
                        <td>1200</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr> ...
```

Comment: This is invalid HTML. A table row isn't a valid child of a div.

Answer (score 0):

fixed it, the complete table must be in the div not just the rows.